# chroot debootstrap problem : no such file or directory

Tags: permissions, qemu, chroot, arm, debootstrap

I would like to run X86 applications on my Jetson Nano using qemu and debootstrap on ubuntu 18.04. Actually I'm following this tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzAoaFOJy7U&t=338s&ab_channel=NovaspiritTech

this is what happened and where I'm freezed :

```
root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# ls

chroot-stretch-i386 log-x86 monta.sh smonta.sh

root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# sudo mount -t sysfs /sys/ ./chroot-stretch-i386/sys/

root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# sudo mount -t proc /proc/ ./chroot-stretch-i386/proc/

root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# sudo mount --bind /dev ./chroot-stretch-i386/dev/

root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# sudo mount --bind /dev/pts ./chroot-stretch-i386/dev/pts

root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# sudo mount --bind /dev/shm ./chroot-stretch-i386/dev/shm/

root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# chroot ./chroot-stretch-i386/ /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage

chroot: impossibile eseguire il comando "/debootstrap/debootstrap": No such file or directory

root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-i386-static ./chroot-stretch-i386/usr/bin/

root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# sudo chroot ./chroot-stretch-i386/ /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage

chroot: impossibile eseguire il comando "/debootstrap/debootstrap": No such file or directory

root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# sudo !!

sudo sudo chroot ./chroot-stretch-i386/ /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage

chroot: impossibile eseguire il comando "/debootstrap/debootstrap": No such file or directory

root@ziomario-desktop:~/Scrivania/qemu-x86# chroot ./chroot-stretch-i386/ /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage

chroot: impossibile eseguire il comando "/debootstrap/debootstrap": No such file or directory
```

below u can see what should have happened :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you skipped the command at 6:51 according to the output you posted on https://pastebin.com/cDbw2nG3. You have to copy `qemu-i386-static` to `./chroot-stretch-i386/usr/bin`:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static chroot-stretch-i386/usr/bin
```

before your execute:

```
sudo chroot ./chroot-stretch-i386/ /debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
```

if your device does not support the `i386` architecture.

You can also check whether the `binfmt-support` package is installed and also run `update-binfmts --display` for checking whether the binfmt entries were registered.

Comment: @Marietto You need to copy `/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static` to `chroot-stretch-i386/usr/bin`. This is a working answer. Sorry I have reading this answer after editing my answer (+1).

Comment: thanks. I've been able to do the second stage succesfully,but then another error is occurred. you can see the full log here : https://pastebin.com/XwkQp91Y

Comment: @Marietto Maybe you could create a symlink from `chfn` to `true` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28953021) answer and rerun the second stage. If you do not need to use Debian `stretch` you could also try to use `buster`, the current stable release.